# Watershed segmentation in Python with skimage does not stop running

Tags: python, scikit-image, watershed

I'm having some trouble with the implementation of a watershed segmentation algorithm in Python using scikit-image.

My sample code is below:

```
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage import feature
import numpy as np

cells = binary_image_of_interest
distance = ndi.distance_transform_edt(cells)

local_maxi = feature.peak_local_max(
    distance,
    footprint=np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.bool),
    indices=False,
    labels = measure.label(cells)
)
```

But when I run the code it seems to continue for a long time (up to 1 h) with no solution.  I'm pretty sure it's not just my machine being slow because other scripts run with times comparable to that on the skimage website.

If anyone would be able to help out it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide a test image?

Comment: [This](https://ibb.co/joKXjv) is a section of the image.

Comment: The calculation finished on my machine, but did take a long time to execute.  I've filed https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2758

Comment: Thanks so much - do you have any thoughts as to why it's so slow? Is it just the amount of objects?